# How to use jest.config.js with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I would like to move my jest config out of my package.json, i am trying to use the --config as suggested [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration) but get the error `argv.config.match is not a function`

## package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --config jest.config.js",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  },
```

## cli

```
hutber@hutber-mac:/var/www/management/node$ npm test -u

> management-fresh@0.1.0 test /var/www/management/node
> react-scripts test --config jest.config.js

Usage: test.js [--config=<pathToConfigFile>] [TestPathPattern]


argv.config.match is not a function
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: I have the same annoying problem and didn't find the solution. I ended up configuring jest with the package.json https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For me appending `-- --config=jest.config.js` worked.

So the whole string `react-scripts test -- --config jest.config.js` in your case.

Answer (score 18):

**TL;DR**

Add `--` before your options.

```
"test": "react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.js",
```

---

The problem here is with `react-scripts` not seeing the options being passed to
it.  We can demonstrate this by running it directly.

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts test --config=jest.config.js
# argv.config.match is not a function

./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.js
# This works.
```

### Variations

How you pass options to scripts varies depending on which versions of **npm** or
**Yarn** you use.  For completeness, here are the results for the variations:

```sh
# This runs, but completely ignores the option.
npm test --config=jest.config.js

# These result in "argv.config.match is not a function," indicating that the
# options were not understood.
npm test -- --config=jest.config.js
yarn test -- --config=jest.config.js
yarn test --config=jest.config.js
```

- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#using-with-yarn
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#using-with-npm-scripts

**create react app** sets up the test script in `package.json` with

```
"test": "react-scripts test",
```

You can set additional options like so.

```
"test": "react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.js",
```

Something like this *might* work if you want to send options through the CLI.

```
"test": "react-scripts test --",
```

```sh
yarn test --bail
# comes through as
react-scripts test -- --bail
```

### Resources

Here are a few resources to explain the different usage.

- https://medium.com/fhinkel/the-curious-case-of-double-dashes-b5e7711698f

Comment: I get an error when I do this - `Invalid testPattern --config=jest.config.js|--coverage=true|--watch|--config|{"roots":["<rootDir>/src"],"collectCoverageFrom":["src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","!src/**/*.d.ts"],"setupFiles"...... Running all tests instead`

Comment: I suspect that when you add `--config`, it ignores the jest config which comes bundled by default with create-react-app.

Comment: @ChasenBettinger, it's because you're using yarn

Comment: I was getting the `Invalid testPattern` error while trying to set testURL (the location.href that jest uses as the origin in requests (for CORS). I ended up doing `DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT=20000 react-app-rewired test --testURL http://origin.domain.com`

Comment: @ChasenBettinger regarding the "Invalid testPattern" error, this is what I did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68912023/99717

Comment: @reergymerej any thoughts how to fix the error from the first comment

Answer (score 14):

For me adding `jest` as key in `package.json` file worked. Added all the required config as object in `jest` key rather than jest.config.js

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text-summary",
      "lcov",
      "cobertura"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/*.test.js"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: This is ideal and I think how CRA would prefer you configure it. The problem is that certain options aren't supported from the package.json (i.e. `haste`)

Answer (score 13):

**tldr**

- `npm install jest --save-dev` (not sure if this is required -- I just did it).
- replace

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    ...
  },
```

with

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest --watch",
    ...
  },
```

- run tests as normal with `npm test`

**Everything**

Adding `-- --config=jest.config.js` sort of work for me: my tests passed, but then I was getting the following error (truncated):

```
Invalid testPattern --config=jest.config.js|--watch|--config|{"roots":["<rootDir>/src"]
...
Running all tests instead.
```

This problem is noted in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878153/how-to-use-jest-config-js-with-create-react-app#comment115799392_63208136).

Here's what's going on:

`npm test` looks in package.json for whatever is in `scripts.test` and runs that. For create-react-app, that's `react-scripts test`. This, in turn, runs
`/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js` ([source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js)) (you can easily print debug this to see what's going on). This script builds up a jest configuration based on your environment. When you add:

```
"test": "react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.js",
```

to `package.json`, this replaces the jest config that `react-scripts test` is trying to create (yea!), but it also munges the arguments that `"test": "react-scripts test"` generates (boo!), so jest thinks you're trying to pass in a test pattern (which is obviously not a valid test pattern).

So, I decided to try running my tests using the jest CLI. At least for me, it worked fine and picked up all of my tests. It automatically looks for `jest.config.js`, so that works, and you can pass `--watch` in to get the same behavior as `react-scripts test`.

Keep in mind that `react-scripts test` seems to be going through a lot of trouble to build up a 'proper' config; I definitely haven't tried to figure all of that out: YMMV. Here's the full set of options it creates in my env. E.g., for `--config` the next element in the array is the config.

```
[
  '--watch',
  '--config',
  '{"roots":["<rootDir>/src"],
      "collectCoverageFrom":["src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"],
      "setupFiles":["<my_root_elided>/node_modules/react-app-polyfill/jsdom.js"],
      "setupFilesAfterEnv":["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"],
      "testMatch":["<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
      "testEnvironment":"jsdom",
      "testRunner":"<my_root_elided>/node_modules/jest-circus/runner.js",
      "transform":{
        "^.+\\\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$":"<my_root_elided>/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
        "^.+\\\\.css$":"<my_root_elided>/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
        "^(?!.*\\\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)":"<my_root_elided>/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/fileTransform.js"},
      "transformIgnorePatterns":["[/\\\\\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\\\\\].+\\\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$",
        "^.+\\\\.module\\\\.(css|sass|scss)$"],
      "modulePaths":[],
      "moduleNameMapper":{"^react-native$":"react-native-web",
      "^.+\\\\.module\\\\.(css|sass|scss)$":"identity-obj-proxy"},
      "moduleFileExtensions":["web.js", "js", "web.ts", "ts", "web.tsx", "tsx", "json", "web.jsx", "jsx", "node"],
      "watchPlugins":["jest-watch-typeahead/filename", "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"],
      "resetMocks":true,
      "rootDir":"<my_root_elided>"}',
  '--env',
  '<my_root_elided>/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js'
]
```

Answer (score -2):

This one got me too!  create react app is a bit tricky as it already contains jest.   I removed the 
`--config jest.config.js` line, and didn't need that extra test.config file.

I also made sure my enzyme file was named setupTests.js.  The testing module will be specifically looking to run that file, so it must be named that.  Also,I had to have it in my src/ folder, where before I had it in a src/test folder. If you are asking the above question you are probably past this point, but wanted to mention just in case.  My setupTests.js looks like:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({
  adapter: new Adapter()
})
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, and obviously worked for others such Tanzeel below me (as he has the same fix, but with some extra notes).

Answer (score -2):

For me, none of the above answers worked. But with the help of documentation, I found out the way around.
For this purpose, place the code you want to configure jest, in `your_project_root_folder/src/setupTests.js`. My `your_project_root_folder/src/setupTests.js` looks like this

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

Enzyme.configure({
    adapter: new Adapter(),
})
```

And one more important point, you need to use `enzyme-adapter-react-16` for `react v16` and `enzyme-adapter-react-15` for `react v15`

Moreover, if you want to use `enzyme-to-json`, you can place the following code in `package.json` file

```
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
  }
```

Answer (score -4):

I would try adding `"test": "jest --no-cache -w 2"` to your package.json. Then run `npm run test`