# jest.config is being ignored

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have the following in my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
};
```

but it's being ignored when I run npm test. Can someone please help?

Here's my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like adding `-- --config=jest.config.js` is enough.

You can try to replace the scripts "test" in package.json by `react-scripts test -- --config=jest.config.js`, else you can set the jest config directly into the package.json

You can find the answer here : [How to use jest.config.js with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878153/how-to-use-jest-config-js-with-create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that you are probablly overriding the defaults so you need to make a require as stated in the documentation [Jest Documentation scroll to defaults](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration)

Just making a module.exports isn't enough.