# Unable to ignore specific files with jest.config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Trying to ignore all index files, but specifically the `src/index.jsx` and `src/reportWebVitals.js` files, however my coverage command still shows up covered lines.

**[My Github repo](https://github.com/leongaban/sked-test/tree/dev)** on the correct `dev` branch where this is an issue.

[image]

According to the docs, it should be as simple as adding the file to `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` and `testPathIgnorePatterns`.

**jest.config**

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    NODE_ENV: 'test',
  },
  restoreMocks: true,
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules',
    'index.js',
    'index.jsx',
    'server/src/config',
    'server/src/app.js',
    'src/index.jsx',
    'src/reportWebVitals.js',
    'tests',
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['text', 'lcov', 'clover', 'html'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['index.js', 'index.jsx', 'src/index.jsx', 'src/reportWebVitals.js'],
  roots: ['<rootDir>/server/tests'],
};
```

Also tried with a much longer version here:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    NODE_ENV: 'test',
  },
  restoreMocks: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/{!(index),}.jsx',
    'src/{!(reportWebVitals),}.js',
    'src/{!(store),}.js'
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules',
    'index.js',
    'index.jsx',
    'server/src/config',
    'server/src/app.js',
    'index.jsx',
    'reportWebVitals.js',
    'store.js',
    'tests',
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['text', 'lcov', 'clover', 'html'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules',
    'index.js',
    'index.jsx',
    'server/src/config',
    'server/src/app.js',
    'index.jsx',
    'reportWebVitals.js',
    'store.js',
    'tests',
  ],
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules',
    'index.js',
    'index.jsx',
    'server/src/config',
    'server/src/app.js',
    'index.jsx',
    'reportWebVitals.js',
    'store.js',
    'tests',
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules',
    'index.js',
    'index.jsx',
    'server/src/config',
    'server/src/app.js',
    'index.jsx',
    'reportWebVitals.js',
    'store.js',
    'tests',
  ],
  roots: ['<rootDir>/server/tests'],
};
```

My package.json scripts

```
"client-dev": "react-scripts start",
"client-build": "react-scripts build",
"client-test": "react-scripts test ./src",
"client-coverage": "react-scripts test ./src --coverage",
```

UPDATE: One interesting thing I noted, I removed all my ignore rules form the jest.config.js and the coverage is still the same, node_modules isn't a problem in the coverage... so now exploring if my project is even picking up the config.

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    NODE_ENV: 'test',
  },
  restoreMocks: true,
  coverageReporters: ['text', 'lcov', 'clover', 'html'],
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can use glob pattern for these files in jest config. Try `src/**/index.{js,jsx}` to ignore all `index.js` and `index.jsx` files in the `src` directory.

Comment: @h-sifat for which rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to explicitly mention your config file path in your test script. If you do so, it will lead to another issue which has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68912023/10055300. It would be ideal to have jest configs in `package.json` itself rather than having a separate file for it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was my jest.config.js is being ignored by the project. Initially when I started working on this project this config was already included which why I kept it rather than using jest config inside of my package.json.

After using the jest rules inside package.json the ignores are working 100% now.

I am unsure as to why the jest.config.js did not work.

```
"jest": {
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules",
    "server/src/config",
    "store.js",
    "index.jsx",
    "index.js",
    "tests"
  ],
  "watchPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules",
    "server/src/config",
    "store.js",
    "index.jsx",
    "index.js",
    "tests"
  ]
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an unejected create-react-app, the only way to override the jest configuration(without ejecting) is to add the allowed configuration keys in `package.json` under the parent key `jest`.

Something like this:

```json
{
  "jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "index.jsx"
    ],
  }
}
```

If you go through the source code for [facebook/create-react-app/.../react-scripts/.../createJestConfig.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js), you will see that react-scripts allows only a fixed set of jest configuration keys to be overridden, and only using the package.json method. It does not support adding your own jest.config.js file. CRA(react-scripts) creates its own jest configuration and uses that to run your tests.

[image]